# Unable to scroll wheel zoom with a Wacom Intuous Pro - Seems to think I'm Pressing Shift?

Tags: hardware

I'm not sure if this is an issue with my tablet drivers, or with blender. I am using a Wacom Intuous Pro with touch is enabled so you can use two fingers to scroll wheel up and down.  I've been using this for ages in blender and it's been no bother.

Then, a few months back, for some reason unbeknownst to me, whenever I try to zoom in on Blender 2.79, the camera pans vertically. (As if I was holding down shift).  On blender 2.8, it just does nothing, but the tooltips at the bottom change to Pan View, Set 3d Cursor, and Move. (Again, as if I was holding down shift)

I've tried reinstalling Blender and my graphics tablet drivers. to no avail. There are no special program specific shortcuts set up in Wacom Tablet Properties.  And it works in every other application and game just fine.

Any thoughts for anything I can check? it just seems to think I'm pressing shift when I scroll wheel.

Also, as an additional thing, this is also true using the Touch Ring, on the side of the tablet. It just really thinks I'm pressing shift.

Wacom Tablet Driver versions are the latest: 6.3.38-2

Answer (score 2):

To solve this simply change one of the touch ring functions, in Wacom Tablet Properties, to "zoom". This will stop the issue.